# WordPress: next_posts_link() doesn't work before page template loop

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I have an archive page template that I've built that has a successful navigation at the end of the loop. However, now I want to add an additional navigation at the top. However, after I copied and pasted the exact code, the 'Previous Entries' displays and links correctly, but 'Next Entries' never shows up as it does in the bottom navigation.

In my page-archive.php file, this is gist of my code:

```
<div class="navigation top">
<?php next_posts_link('Next Entries') ?> <!-- Doesn't appear to show up! -->
<?php previous_posts_link('Previous Entries') ?>
</div>

<?php $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts("showposts=1&paged=$page");
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="navigation bottom">
<?php next_posts_link('Next Entries') ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('Previous Entries') ?>
</div>
```

I understand that a Page template is not the ideal method to create an archive page, so if there is a different method for producing a full customizable archive page, please inform me!

Currently, I'm using my home.php file to display static content, so the page-archive.php is a method to direct users to the actual "Blog" portion of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put this string:

```
  <?php $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts("showposts=1&paged=$page");?>
```

to the very top of the page. You need to do that because `next_posts_link` and `prev_posts_link` calls use some global variables set by `query_posts` call.